# genus of regular bipartite graph

Tags: topological-graph-theory

Is there a formula for the genus of a bipartite graph with 2 sets of m vertices, where each vertex has order 3? I.e. if m=3 this is K(3,3). But I'm interested in larger m.

Comment: I'm sure it depends on which such graph you're looking at. E.g., you could just have a union of several copies of $K_{3,3}$, which would have genus one.

Comment: The Desargues graph https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desargues_graph for example has genus two.

Comment: Care to interact with the comments, Tony?

Comment: I should have added "connected" to the specs. The Desargues graph does

Comment: not look bipartite to me. Am I missing something?

Comment: Now I understand your point. I misinterpreted "Let G(n, d) denote a connected regular bipartite graph on 2n vertices and of degree d. " as implying that there

Comment: was only one. My question probably doesn't make sense. Sorry.

Comment: Well, it says at the Wikipedia link that it's bipartite. Try labeling the vertices alternately A and B, and I think you'll find that no two vertices with the same label are adjacent.